# General properties? of divisibility of semigroups

Tags: divisibility, semigroups, semigroup-homomorphism

Referencing [Grillet's Semigroups](https://books.google.ee/books/about/Semigroups.html?id=yM544W1N2UUC&redir_esc=y) pp 151.

**Problem** Prop. V.3 3.2 Grillet asserts that when $A,S$ are semigroups, then $A$ and $S$ both divide $A\times S$. (He offers no explanation, it's supposedly trivial)

Nothing to see here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $S_1$ and $S_2$ are nonempty. Then the projections from $S_1 \times S_2$ to $S_1$ and to $S_2$ are both surjective morphisms. Thus $S_1$ and $S_2$ divide $S_1 \times S_2$.

Comment: I am confused. What do you mean "projection"? To me that means a mapping that is idempotent or "the projection" from a set onto its  quotient. How do you explicitly define your mapping?

Comment: Oh, it suffices to construct an injective homomorphism $S\to T$, then $S\prec T$.

Comment: First projection $p_1(s_1, s_2) = s_1$, second projection $p_2(s_1, s_2) = s_2$. Both are surjective, thus $S_1$ and $S_2$ are quotients of $S_1 \times S_2$.

Comment: That much is obvious, but your projections have to satisfy some kind of multiplication, since it's a semigroup homomorphism we're looking for. $p_1((s,t)(u,v)) = p_1(s\,{}^tu, tv) = s\,{}^tu\overset{?}= p_1(s,t) p_1(u,v)$.

Comment: I finally had a look at Grillet's book. You are confusing the direct product $A \times S$ (which occurs in Proposition V.3.2) and the semidirect product $A \times_\varphi S$.

Comment: Forget everything I said, I am such an idiot, this is so obvious :/